# why luacode environments do not ignore lua comment -- lines?

Tags: luatex, lua, luacode

I do understand (a little) the difference between `luacode` and `luacode*` But I almost fell of my seat when something I wrote inside a commented line caused lualatex to scream at me.  I changed `luacode*` to `luacode` and got an error due to something in a comment.

I would have thought a comment is a comment, and this tells lualatex to please do not look at anything on this line, regardless if I am running `luacode` or `luacode*`

This compiles OK

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}% 
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function foo()
--print("\begin{verbatim}".."\end{verbatim}")
tex.print("done")
end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\directlua{foo()}
\end{document}
```

Changed it to luacode, and now it failed

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}% 
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function foo()
--print("\begin{verbatim}".."\end{verbatim}")
tex.print("done")
end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\directlua{foo()}
\end{document}
```

error is

```
lualatex foo2.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
.....
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)))
! Undefined control sequence.
\luacode@begin ...#1\relax \edef \luacode@endmark 
                                                  {\string \end {\@currenvir...

l.10 \end{luacode}                         
?
```

But the line is commented out !!  really?

From lua help:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am was trying things.  This makes it hard to play around with code and comment lines, if I have to worry also about what is inside comments affecting parser.

**Question is** : Why comments lines are not ignored in luacode?

Comment: luacode package manual lists which constructs work in which form in a table on page 2. (lucode and luacode* are both documented as supporting `--` comments.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change the line

```
--print("\begin{verbatim}".."\end{verbatim}")
```

to

```
--print("\\begin{verbatim}".."\\end{verbatim}")
```

your code will compile just fine whether you employ the `luacode` or the `luacode*` environment.

In the `luacode` environment, TeX macros are expanded. Since Lua and TeX "see" the backslash character differently, you need to write `\\`, which Lua will re-write as `\` before passing it to TeX; of course, `\` is what you *want* TeX to see.

In contrast, in the `luacode*` environment, TeX macros are not expanded, and hence it doesn't matter what comes after the `--` comment initiator.

Comment: +1 for `\\ ` (even though `\\begin`  is in a comment here, that answers what would be the next question:-)

Answer (score 7):

The luacode package manual lists which constructs work in which form in a table on page 2. (`lucode` and `luacode*` are both documented as supporting `--` comments.)

The problem is occurring *before* lua is being called as you have not prevented `\begin` and `\end` expanding in TeX while the chunk to be passed to lua is constructed. You need `\string\begin` and `\string\end` or similar (or better `\\` as Mico notes as you would  want `\\` not `\` if it were not a comment) .

The whole point of `luacode*` is it changes the catcode of `\` so `\begin` is taken as 6 characters, not a tex command to be expanded.

The error is unrelated to the Lua comment syntax, Lua never started, you get the same error from

```
\begin{luacode}
 a b wibble
?? xx ("\begin{verbatim}".."\end{verbatim}")
 @@@@
end
\end{luacode}
```